# Analyze text to create tags automatically in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags

I plan to use acts_as_taggable_on gem for my Post class. However, I would like to extract and generate new tags from the content of the post.

For example, if the title of the Post is "How should I solve this algebra question", I would like to generate a new algebra tag (but not for other words).

Is there a gem to do this, and if not, how should I go about this? (i.e., detect sensible words to create tags)

Thank you.

Comment: Is the assumption that 'algebra' would have already existed before this Post object was created or the tag would be created after creation of the Post object?

Comment: I would prefer not to have to specify algebra before Post created.

Answer (score 5):

There are several tools to do that

You can take a look at http://engtagger.rubyforge.org/

http://martin.ankerl.com/2007/01/09/textanalyzer-automatically-extract-characteristic-words/

or take a look aat this http://www.viget.com/extend/tagging-text-automatically/ ,which uses yahoo's term extraction service.

Comment: Wonder is there any modern gem to do this?